# How do i make y-axis to be in an ascending order in matplotlib.animation? Sentdex tutorial

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    graph_data = open('example.txt','r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Is there another way to write the code such that y-axis is in ascending order?
If so. where should I find it? This is from sentdex matplotlib tutorial

Comment: You need to convert your strings to numbers. Since it seems this code comes up a lot, may I ask where you got that from? Maybe one can edit it such that not every other week someone falls into that trap.

Comment: There is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w8jk0r4lxA) which actually does convert the strings to integers `xs.append(int(x))`. There is also [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmYPzESC5YY&lc=UgxJiaDSeOJgiutp4Rh4AaABAg) where the first visible comment below the video tells you the solution.

Comment: it is from sentdex youtube tutorial on matplotlib series. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48408645/python-axis-values-not-in-order https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmYPzESC5YY&t=455s

Comment: haha didn't realise that. thx for the comment

Comment: I don't have an account for youtube, but feel free to comment with the solution below to help future readers over there.

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is to not do all the stuff manually and rely on numpy reading the data. Also, not clearing the axes in each loopstep may be beneficial.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([],[])

def animate(i):
    x,y = np.loadtxt("data/example.txt", unpack=True, delimiter=",")
    line.set_data(x,y)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```